# unrequested permissions not declared in androidmanifest--crashlytics maybe?

Tags: android, crashlytics

I've just noticed that my app has new permission requests that I have not explicitly declared in my AndroidManifest.xml. I didn't see these declared in any of the manifests in the 
"intermediates" directory created by gradle, and the only dependency that I declare without an explicit version is crashlytics (as they suggest to do), i.e:

compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'

The new permissions found in the full manifest are:

```
<android:uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
    <android:uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <android:uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

So what my guess is that whatever new version of crashlytics is now requesting this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're using Gradle to build, you can add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml to remove the permission:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove" />
```

Comment: My assumption Crashlytics was doing this intentionally was incorrect, please see @Mike's answer.

Comment: In my case, the culprit was actually AndroidPlot not specifying a targetSdk, which caused the build tools to automatically include the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

Comment: I get the same. How did you remove it? Is the only way to use tools:node remove? This is what my merge shows: `android:uses-permission#android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
IMPLIED from AndroidManifest.xml:2:1 reason: com.androidplot has a targetSdkVersion < 4
android:uses-permission#android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
IMPLIED from AndroidManifest.xml:2:1 reason: com.androidplot has a targetSdkVersion < 4
android:uses-permission#android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
IMPLIED from AndroidManifest.xml:2:1 reason: com.androidplot requested WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
`

Comment: With the current build tools, the only way I have found to remove this permission is to use the `tools:node="remove"` explicit instruction: changing the targetSdkVersion in AndroidPlot just shifted the blame to the next library, then to a jar (which of course doesn't specify anything).

Comment: This worked. Few other stackoverflows have mentioned it as <permission>, that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue within the Android Gradle plugin version 1.0.0-rc1 that may be causing the behavior to happen: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81017

Version 1.0.0 has a fix for this.

Crashlytics only requires the INTERNET permission to send crash reports.

Comment: Note that the "fix" merely better documents why the permission was automatically added (in manifest-merger-*-report.txt). If you want to force the permission off, see my answer below.