# Overriding Gradle Remote Dependency's targetSdkVersion in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

So today we did a release of an app and unfortunately we didn't notice a new permission had been added which is `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE`.

A few users pointed out that a new permission category had been added to the app which was

> Device ID & call information
>
> read phone status and identity

After some looking into this I found that this is linked to the aforementioned permission however I don't have that in any of my manifests. After a search on my project, I found it was contained in the manifest-merger-release-report.txt.

```
android:uses-permission#android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE
IMPLIED from AndroidManifest.xml:6:1 reason: com.getpebble.android.kit has a targetSdkVersion < 4
```

I don't want this permission to be requested of the user, especially if it's only because an external library hasn't got its targetSdkVersion set.

I make this a dependency of my module using the following.

```
compile 'com.getpebble:pebblekit:2.6.0@aar'
```

**MY QUESTION**

How do I override the library's `targetSdkVersion` without access to it's `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

**UPDATE**

After looking at the library's source code on GitHub I can in fact see that it does have its `targetSdkVersion` and `minSdkVersion` set correctly so the prompt in the `manifest-merger-release-report.txt` is incorrect.

Comment: You could fork the library on github and remove the permissions you don't need and then add it to your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override 'uses-permission' attribute coming from a library, you can use [Selector](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger#TOC-Selector):

> **Selector**
>
> Each tools:node or tools:attr declaration can be augmented by a
>   tools:selector attribute which is contextual information on whether or
>   not the merging strategy should be applied to the current lower
>   priority XML description. For instance, this is useful when removing a
>   permission only if coming for one particular library as opposed to any
>   library:
>
> ```
> <permission
>       android:name="permissionOne"
>       tools:node="remove"
>       tools:selector="com.example.lib1">
> ```

Comment: This didn't work. The answer that worked is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/27542669/406295